# JQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to allow someone to type the date in and still verify that the date in the box is correct. If it is not I want to change the style from inputNormal to inputError and let them know this is not a valid date.  I also want the date to be from tomorrow forward.

When I try to do this using OnBlur and they click on the DatePicker it fires the onBlur before putting in the JQuery DatePicker date.  So the style changes but the date gets filled.

How can I resolve these both issues?

The JavaScript and JQuery Includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/javascript/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/javascript/formValidation.js" ></script>

<SCRIPT>
    $(function() {
        $( "#contractExpire" ).datepicker({ altField: 'input#contractExpire', altFormat: 'dd M yy',minDate: new Date(<cfoutput>#year(2011,1-1,1) });
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

In the HTML Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `blur` handler, try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // your original blur code
});
```

This will make it wait until the rest of the event has been handled before getting back to the blur code.